# Trying to call third party cosole function from my laravel application

Tags: laravel-5, php-easybook

Am trying to use this brilliant app [easybook-project](http://www.easybook-project.org) with my laravel ebooka applicatin but the app I have mentioned uses console commands. Is there anyway I can consume this console commands from my laravel ebook application for ebook conversion?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the normal PHP `exec` command, to call the 3rd party commands.
Please find the [link for the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).